# How to Insert LastRow function and Text in If Statements in Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very lengthy formula that I am attempting to set via script in particular cell in the last row of a specified column. This is the formula:

```
sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,8).setFormula("=IF(AND($S$2=1,F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*3),IF(AND($S$2=1,(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F25-6)/8)+1+(G25/2))*3),IF(AND($S$2=1,(F25-12)/8=TRUNC((F25-12)/8)),((((F25-12)/8)+2+(G25/2))*3),if(AND($S$2=1,(F25-18)/8=TRUNC((F25-18)/8)),((((F25-18)/8)+3+(G25/2))*3),IF(AND($S$2=0,F25/8=TRUNC(F25/8)),(((F25/8)+(G25/2))*5),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-6)/8=TRUNC((F25-6)/8)),((((F25-6)/8)+3+(G25/2))*5),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-12)/8=TRUNC((F25-12)/8)),((((F25-12)/8)+3+(G25/2))*5),if(AND($S$2=0,(F25-18)/8=TRUNC((F25-18)/8)),((((F25-18)/8)+3+(G25/2))*5),0))))))))");
```

I would like to be able to be able to refer the F25 and G25 to just refer to the F and G columns in the last row such as this formula:

```
sheet.getRange("H" + (lastrow+1)).setFormula("=E" + (lastrow+1) + "-(F" + (lastrow+1) + "*1.5)");
```

In an ideal world I would also be able to swap out the $S$2=0 to be $S$2="Full Mastic" and check for text rather than a value but I run into issues when inserting the additional parentheses required for the text to function when the formula is inserted into the spreadsheet. Thanks for any help. I know the formula is a little ridiculous...

Comment: I'm wondering if you'd be better off with a custom formula that calls an apps script function. [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish with this script? I agree with @SandyGood that this is probably time for a custom formula called via a script function, and if you let us know what you're looking to do we may be able to help you figure out exactly what's best :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time you see 25 replace it with: (including quotes)

```
" + (lastrow+1) + "
```

for your text items escape the quotes by preceding them with a backslash which will cause the quotes to be inserted as text instead of being interpreted as text delimiter.

```
$S$2=\"Full Mastic\"
```

Comment: The first part works great. As far as the use single quotes, do you mean use '$S$2=Full Mastic'... rather than $S$2="Full Mastic"....    because that seams to insert the words in the formula but once it is in the spreadsheet it causes an error and it can't read that text.

Comment: Yes that is what I had been trying. When the formula is then inserted into the spreadsheet it says error because I think it the text needs the double quotes around it to work.

Comment: are you sure you used $S$2='Full Mastic' and not '$S$2=Full Mastic' as shown in your comment?

Comment: Yes, this was the beginning of the formula: sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,8).setFormula("=IF(AND($S$2='Full Mastic',F" + (lastrow+1) + "/8=TRUNC(F" + (lastrow+1) + "/8)),(((F" + (lastrow+1) + "/8)+(G" + (lastrow+1) + "/2))*3),

Comment: I don't think it's the single quotes. After the formula has been inserted and is returning an error see if you can correct it by swapping out with double quotes. I don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: If I swap out for double quotes after the function is inserted it works. It says parse error otherwise.

Comment: in that case, the only thing I would think to try would be to swap out all single quotes for double quotes and all double quotes for single quotes in the setFormula statement

Comment: I reversed all of the quotes and that works! Thanks for the input!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. There might have been a quicker way by escaping the original quotes but that would have added more special characters to a very complex formula.